# Blogging platform for shared hosting?

Tags: wordpress, blog, shared-hosting

First of all, this is not for flame wars. So, please do not bash some blogging platform :P

I have a shared hosting account. I want to setup a blog on it. Now, the thing is that as it is shared hosting, I do not have as much bandwidth as some expensive hosting. I have tried using Wordpress with the caching plugins configured. It still does not seem to speed it much.

Also if I create a simple PHP website, the speed is fine. Can someone suggest me some lightweight platform?

Comment: Since you tagged this question with Wordpress you should explain why you aren't going to use it.

Comment: @JohnConde he said `I have tried using Wordpress with the caching plugins configured. It still does not seem to speed it much.`

Comment: If WordPress is slow. My advice is get a new host, it should run perfectly fine out of the box on most hosts. Your host is probably loaded with too many sites on one server

Comment: How did I miss that? It's been a long week. Time to get off of the computer and relax for a bit!

Comment: @Anagio I was keeping my fingers crossed for that suggestion and it turns out everyone suggests changing hosts. :( I do not wan't to do that as I will just waste my money. :( I am a student.

Comment: Then if you want to save money I suggest using http://www.wordpress.com or http://www.blogger.com

Comment: You're wasting your money by using a web host with subpar performance. Wordpress is not a very resource intensive application. In terms of performance, it's very typical of most common blogging platforms. So if your web host struggles to run Wordpress, then you're not gonna have much success with any of the other major blogging platforms out there, and you'll need to stick with a more obscure & bare-bone blogging platform without standard blogging/CMS features and modern UI. It makes more sense to switch to a competent web host, which you can get for as little as $5~6/month these days.

Comment: You can also find hosting providers for $1 per month, some are better than others. It's been a lot of years since I used them so I have no suggestions. I feel we all answered your question, either change hosts, use a hosted blogging service as mentioned above, or try to find a stripped down CMS such as 10 year old CGI/Perl scripts.

Comment: Can you expand on what "caching plugins" you have configured? You can offset some of your static resources to free services like CloudFlare (using W3TC) etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress can, per se, under some conditions be slow. But if plain PHP work good on the same host, you have to think about DB-backend of WordPress (MySQL) also - host may be fast, only database slow.

Anyway, some not oberbloated Blog-engines, which you can try

**DB-backend**

- Serendipity (s9y)
- MaxSite CMS
- Dotclear (require PHP 5.3.*)
- PivotX

**Flat-files backend**

- Mosquito Blood Mary
- Rubma-XML
- Simple PHP Blog

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Install WordPress on the server.
2. Read up on securing your site on a shared hosting account the best
   you can.
3. Don't turn to a plug-in to achieve the latest trendy slider or image
   gallery. Only add a plug-in or script if it compliments your site. A
   flashy plug-in doesn't make up for a crappy website. Content is
   still #1.
4. If you do install plug-ins make sure to look at the last time it
   was updated and the number of downloads and ratings (all available
   from the WordPress plug-in repository download section.
5. Don' just "hack" WordPress to force the features you want. WordPress
   is very diverse and can handle about any requirement using the
   WordPress API.

WordPress isn't slow, rather the user that doesn't take the time to learn the ins and outs of the WordPress core functions makes it slow by hacking at it and forcing a bowling ball through a water hose.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a simple plugin called W3 Total Cache...

It speeds up the database, CSS, javascript and overall loading of the page.

You can also subscribe to some CDN networks and plug that information into W3 Total Cache so that the CDN caches your blog for your users.

I'm using a free hosting server based somewhere in Eastern Europe (yeah, that's the worst thing!) but my blog loads pretty fast due to this plugin (I don't even have the CDN concept setup)...